# Filtering Symbols Out of Command Line Input in Java

Tags: java, string, command-line, c-strings

I am working on a simple method in Java where I take single string from the input, say:
    username@192.168.1.1:2531

And I need to separate the **username**, **ip address/host**, and **port** into three different strings. My current thinking is to convert the whole input into a char[], run it through a loop marking the indices which the **'@'** and the **':'** occupy. Then using the offset constructor for a new String to construct each individual string for username, ip/host, and port.

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;

public class StringSymbolParse {
public static void main(String[] args){
    String uname; 
    String host;
    int port;   //uname@ip:host

    String total = args[0];
    System.out.println("Input: " + args[0]);
    char totalChar[] = total.toCharArray();
    int size = totalChar.length;

    int markerAt = 0; //marks last filtered symbol placement;
    int markerColon = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
        if((totalChar[i] == '@')){
            markerAt = i;
        }
        else if(totalChar[i] == ':'){
            markerColon = i;                
        }
    }
    System.out.println("MarkerAT: " + markerAt);
    System.out.println("MarkerColon: " + markerColon);
    uname = new String(totalChar,0,(markerAt));
    System.out.println("Username: " + uname);
    host = new String(totalChar, 8, );
    port = Integer.parseInt(new String(totalChar, (markerColon),  size));


    System.out.println("Username: " + uname);
    System.out.println("Host: " + host);
    System.out.println("Port: " + port);
   }
}
```

`

Comment: `host = new String(totalChar, 8, );`  - wrong syntax. What did you want here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use split method of String class

```
        String s = "username@192.168.1.1:2531";
        String[] arr = s.split("@|:");
        for (String str : arr) {
            System.out.println(str);
        }
```

Comment: Nice use of `|` in split(). Not as strict as my full regex, but valid and simpler, assuming loose handling is ok. Up-vote from me.

Answer (score 2):

For something like that, a [regular expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) is your friend.

```
String text = "username@192.168.1.1:2531";

Matcher m = Pattern.compile("([^@]*)@([^:@]*):(.*)").matcher(text);
if (m.matches()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
    System.out.println(m.group(2));
    System.out.println(m.group(3));
}
```

*Output*

```
username
192.168.1.1
2531
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`String.split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method.

```
String s = "username@192.168.1.1:2531";
String[] arr = s.split("@");
String username = arr[0];
String ipAdd = arr[1].split(":")[0];
String port = arr[1].split(":")[1];
System.out.println("Username : " + username);
System.out.println("IP address : " + ipAdd);
System.out.println("Port : " + port);
```

**Output:**

```
Username : username
IP address : 192.168.1.1
Port : 2531
```